# Create Average Column at the end of Active Row using VBA in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, olap

I am very new to VBAs and require your kind assistance.

I have an OLAP pivot table where changes can be made using slicers.
I want to calculate the average of 'n' columns (excluding the total column) and place it on the last blank cell of each row, for example N6:N13, however as data is added the pivot overwrites the column, meaning if an additional column is added to the pivot, then the average column is now created on column O. This will require the initial average data to be deleted before the pivot updates and then rerun the average column macro again.

n in this case is referenced in cell D2 as Last 2, Last 5, Last 10.

I tried writing a few codes but have not been successful.

```
Sub AddAverageColumn()

'declare variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("City Sheet")
Set MR = Range("B5:XFD5")
Set Period = Range("D2")

'Delete Existing Average Column
    For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value = "Average" Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next

' Select empty column next to last active cell in row
ws.Range("XFD5").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select

' Add header for average column
ActiveCell = "Average"
Selection.Font.Bold = True    

' Select cell below excluding total column and calculate average
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Select

'(no idea how to calculate the average and place answer in the desired column)
'For Last 2 
For Each cell In Period
  If cell.Value = "Last 2" Then

 'For Last 5
   If cell.Value = "Last 5" Then

 'For Last 10
    If cell.Value = "Last 10" Then

 'Autofill Average column  (no idea what to do here). 

'Also need the average data to be deleted when updating the pivot table with slicers, to prevent the error:
'There's already data in [City Sheet.Xlsm]City Sheet. Do you want to replace it? 
'and then rerun the average calculation column again in the next empty column still excluding totals column.

Next  

End Sub
```

[image: see picture here]

Thank you.

Comment: *"I tried writing a few codes but have not been successful."* please [edit] your question and add these attempts ([Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) and explain what went wrong. We need to see where you get stuck or errors in order to help you fixing it. We cannot write the code for you but we are good in fixing stuff or point out what is wrong so you can fix it.

Comment: updated with code